# What does this error mean in cloudwatch console in aws?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have lambda for removing the users role. I have similar lambda function for updating users group which is working fine but removing them from the group isn't.

This is my lamda:

```js
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')#, region_name="eu-central-1")
    try:
        client.admin_remove_user_from_group(
            UserPoolId="user-pool-id",
            Username=event["email"],
            GroupName=event["role"],
        )
        print("User: %s" % event["email"] % "was removed from" % event["role"])
        return 0
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: %s" % e)
        return 1
```

And when I submit my delete request i don't get any errors expect I see this following in the cloudwatch console for that lambda.

[image]

And this is my function to use that api:

```
export const removeUserGroup = async (email, role) => {
  const jwtHeader = await getJWTHeader()
  const query = `${API_GW.DEV_API_URI}/users/removeusergroup?email=${email}&role=${role}`
  const deletedGroup = await axios.delete(
    query,
    jwtHeader
  )
  return deletedGroup
}
```

I also know that I am getting the email and the role values because the changing the users group does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is presumably `KeyError: 'email'` in reality, and it is happening because the `event` object that your Lambda function received does not actually contain an item with the key `email`, so `event['email']` throws KeyError.

Retrieve it as follows:

```
event['queryStringParameters']['email']
```

Note that Unless you have a specific reason not to, you should configure [Lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) otherwise you will have to explicitly create a [custom integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html) to map/transform the payload.

Comment: Didnt seem to work

Comment: Did you log `event`? Can you include the non-sensitive parts of it? Did you try adding a KeyError exception handler (before your default exception handler) and did it catch the exception?

Comment: How can I do that? I mean log that and add that to my above lamda function?

Comment: Yes, print the value of `event` so you can see what it contains. The logs will be available in the usual place (CloudWatch Logs).

Comment: this is the only thing i see expection email

Comment: If you modify your code to `print(event)`, deploy the changed code, and then re-test, it will log the value of `event` to CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: When I added ```    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: %s" % e)
        print(event)
        return 1``` I saw this is the cloudwatch log now `{}`

Comment: and saw this also [ERROR] KeyError: 'email'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    print(event["email"])

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my answer suggests is the problem. You're using `event["email"]` in multiple places and that's incorrect. The `event` dict does not have an `email` key. It's probably under `queryStringParameters` and accessible via `event['queryStringParameters']['email']`. Change all instance of `event["email"]`.

Comment: Also, make sure you have configured API Gateway correctly for Lambda Proxy integration (see [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-apigateway-pass-query-parameters-lambda)].

Comment: I have logged the api gateway as well and the query strings are being send but they are lost before it reaches the lambda it seems.

Comment: Related to my previous comment, what Lambda integration do you have configured in API Gateway? Unless you have a specific reason not to, you should configure Lambda proxy integration otherwise you have to explicitly map the payload.

Comment: I got the username now to display on the log. But now I see this Exception: 'queryStringParameters'
Exception: 'queryStringParameters'

Comment: What does `event` contain at this point? Add it to the post.

Comment: I got it working now, I just had to remove the ['queryStringParameters'] in front of the event when added those mapping things